# Using an event listener to change the state of a checkbox on click

Tags: javascript

I'd like to prevent the default behaviour when clicking on a checkbox (its new state will depend on an API response).

First I deactivate the default behaviour :

```
cb.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Then I try to change myself the state of the checkbox :

```
cb.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log("Before : " + this.checked);
    this.checked = !this.checked;
    console.log("After : " + this.checked);
}

-> // If I start with a checked checkbox :
-> Before : false
-> After : true

-> // If I start with an unchecked checkbox :
-> Before : true
-> After : false
```

But with this I have two problems :

1. the state doesn't seem to change visually.
2. The displayed value for my checkbox's `checked` attribute is the negative value of it's state right before toggling it and I don't understand why (`false` when I start with a checked checkbox and `true` if it's not).

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pqay9b0u/62/).

I also tried to bind the event listener to the `change` event.

Comment: #2: The state has already changed before the onclick event fires. #1: Due to the item 2, the script actually changes the state back to the previous state.

Comment: What exactly solved the problem? Using `oninput`? I retracted that edit, since I suppose the state is changed also before the oninput event fires too ..? I.e. the solution would be to do nothing with the checked property in the handler.

Comment: @Teemu Nevermind. I used this event the wrong way so my listener wasn't triggered, making my code falling back on the default behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

What I have tried is changed visual state on `mousedown` and skipped event prop on `click`

```
var cb = document.getElementById("checkbox");
cb.addEventListener("click", function(e) {       
    e.preventDefault();
});
cb.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log("Before : " + this.checked, e.target.checked);
    e.target.checked = !this.checked;
    console.log("After : " + this.checked);
});
```

Comment: Can you explain what this answer offers?  Code without an explanation isn't really worth much to anyone who comes across this question looking for help.

Comment: Added explanation @Archer , Thanks

Comment: @anshuVersatile Thank you for this answer, but what does it bring to set `e.target.checked` rather than `this.checked`? http://jsfiddle.net/pqay9b0u/123/

Comment: @vmonteco i have just added some code i tried... you can use `this.checked`  http://jsfiddle.net/pqay9b0u/126/